# Finding the angle of elevation in a projectile

Tags: applications

[image]

> Let $\theta$ be the angle of elevation

---

$x(t) = x_0 + u_0t + \frac{1}{2} at^2$

> where $x(t)=0$ and $x_0=50m$ , And $u_0$ is vertically resolved initial component of the velocity

I applied this for the vertical resolved motion which gives:

$-50 = (-600\sin \theta) t - \frac{1}{2}gt^2$

---

Then for the horizontal (horizontal component) motion I used :

$x = vt$

Which gives:

$12000 = (600 \cos \theta) t$

$t=\frac{1200}{600 \cos \theta}$

Substitute this as $t$ for the first equation:

$$-50=(- 600\sin \theta) \frac{1200}{ 600 \cos \theta}-5 (\frac{1200}{600 \cos \theta})^2$$

$$-50=(- \sin \theta) \frac{1200}{ \cos \theta}- \frac{20}{ \cos^2 \theta}$$

> Multiplying each term by $cos^2 \theta$

$$-50 \cos^2 \theta=- 1200 \sin \theta \cos \theta- 20$$

How to solve this equation, Please help. **Thanks**.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$-50 \cos^2 \theta=- 1200 \sin \theta \cos \theta- 20$

Divide by $\cos^2\theta $  :
$-50 =- 1200 \tan \theta- 20(1+\tan^2\theta)$

Notice that its just a quadratic in $\tan \theta$, you can solve it by using quadratic formula

Comment: (upvotes!) Thank you soooo sooooo much :)

Comment: np :) wish there is a simpler method for finding the angle.. did you try solving it by using conservation of energy ?

Comment: that's not possible. And this was the only method taught to us so far.

Comment: Ohk, I've noticed a small typo in your work... you're using 1200m for horizontal distance instead of 12000m ?

Comment: thanks spotted it :) it's a mistake